# Push nodejs app from subdirectory of GitHub repo to openshift

Tags: node.js, git, github, openshift

I have a private GitHub repo which looks like this:

```
[Project root]
- angular
- nodejs
```

> Of course, it would be cleaner to separate these two projects into two
>   repos but due to the limited amount of private repos on GitHub I
>   decided to place both parts into the same repo.

Is there a way I can work with my own GitHub repo and push a new version of a nodejs application to OpenShift without having to use OpenShift's git repo?

I remember that CloudFoundry - another PaaS - has its own CLI tool which simply allows you to write `cf push <app>`, no need to have a git repo at CF. Is there something similar with `rhc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (and probably best) solution to this problem is to use gitlab (my preference) or another service such as bitbucket for hosting private repos.  Gitlab offers free unlimited private repos.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Afterwards, you just run `git remote add gitlab [gitlab-url]` and later on, `git push gitlab master` (for your repo) or `git push origin master` (for OpenShift's repo)?